# find the difference between two columns in specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following columns from one data frame

```
 0         1585742136995  
 1         1585742137014
 2         1585742137035
 3         1585742137058
 4         1585742137080
          ...      
 177809    1585570661653
 177810    1585570661675
 177811    1585570661686
 177812    1585570661709
 177813    1585570661731
```

Name: acctimestamp, Length: 177814, dtype: int64>

and

```
0         1585742136982
1         1585742136996
2         1585742137015
3         1585742137036
4         1585742137058
          ...      
177809    1585570661632
177810    1585570661653
177811    1585570661676
177812    1585570661698
177813    1585570661710
Name: gyrtimestamp, Length: 177814, dtype: int64>
```

I want to start from 299 row and by 200 rows to find and print the difference between two columns (acctimestamp, gyrtimestamp)

so let's say at `299+200=499 row` what is the difference between the 2 columns. After that what is the difference in 699 row And I want to do this for all the len of the data frame.

I am facing difficulties with the for loop can you help me a little bit?
how a loop like this would be?

i write this `df['diff'] = df['acctimestamp'] - df['gyrtimestamp']` but it only show me the difference line by line

how to start from `499` row print the difference and print every `200` row?

i try this code:

```
for i in range (len(df)):
   i=200
   df1=df.loc[299+i, "acctimestamp" ]-df.loc[299+i, "gyrtimestamp"]
```

but the counter print the difference in line `499` and do not continue all the way to the end of the data frame

Comment: Please share the erroneous code and identify which line(s) is causing the problem.

Comment: hi, your request seems simple but its not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: hi i write more thinks in order to be more specific. Hope to be ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range (99,len(df),200):
    try:
       df1=df.loc[i+200,'acctimestamp'] - df.loc[i+200,'gyrtimestamp']
       print(df1)
    except: 
       print('End')
```

Is what you're looking for? Step is 200. So **i** will take 299 -> 499 -> 699 etc.., and you're taking only the rows between **i** ( 299 ) and **i** + 200 ( 499 ) and so on.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer I want to print in the beginning the value from the subtraction of
acctimestamp and gyrtimestamp in line 299. And then to print the difference every 200 rows

Comment: so with your code i take 29499    225
29500    207
29501    227
29502    228
29503    225
        ... 
29565    223
29566    223
29567    210
29568    212
29569    213

i like something 299line :value of subtraction, 499line: value of subtraction etcc

Comment: @Bletz in line 299 the difference is 10 in line 499 is 23 etc

Comment: i edited the code so it takes only the 299th row, then the 499th row etc.. don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: i take error: KeyError: 29699.  what is this? i have 29570 rows in my df

Comment: Because you hit the end of the dataframe and it didn't find the index. Now if you want to save every difference and not the last one, i suggest you start appending the results in a dataframe instead of assigning a new dataframe containing one row of difference each time.

Comment: so what to do how to stop so to not go out of index? and why you put 99 must start from 299 sorry for so many questions

Comment: i starts at 99, but you will access 99+200. so you eventually start at 299. I added an exception to print 'End' when you encounter an index error. so when you see 'End' printed, you know it hit the end of the df.

Comment: yeah that works thank you so much. One last question. How to take the max value from the printed values